# Difference between sql when using Func as a select vs inline select

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to understand why the sql for these two statements are different (The difference appears to be in determining whether to added SignedXml in the select or use a case statement.  But why?).

```
myTable.Where(p => p.OwnerID.Equals(owner) && p.FolderID == folderId)
       .Select(source => new SignedNativeAnalysis
       {
          ID = source.ID,
          Name = source.Name,
          Created = source.Created,
          FolderID = source.FolderID,
          Locked = source.Locked,
          Modified = source.Modified,
          OwnerID = source.OwnerID,
          IsSigned = source.SignedXml != null
       });
```

which generates something like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[FolderID] AS [FolderID], 
[Extent1].[Locked] AS [Locked], 
[Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
[Extent1].[OwnerID] AS [OwnerID], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[SignedXml] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ([Extent1].[SignedXml] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[NativeAnalyses] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[OwnerID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[FolderID] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1
```

vs when I'm using a function for the select:

```
myTable.Where(p => p.OwnerID.Equals(owner) && p.FolderID == folderId)
       .Select(Select);
```

and Select is

```
private SignedNativeAnalysis Select(NativeAnalysis source)
{
      return new SignedNativeAnalysis
      {
        ID = source.ID,
        Name = source.Name,
        Created = source.Created,
        FolderID = source.FolderID,
        Locked = source.Locked,
        Modified = source.Modified,
        OwnerID = source.OwnerID,
        IsSigned = source.SignedXml != null
      };
}
```

which generates something like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[ModelXml] AS [ModelXml], 
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
[Extent1].[OwnerID] AS [OwnerID], 
[Extent1].[SignedXml] AS [SignedXml], 
[Extent1].[FolderID] AS [FolderID], 
[Extent1].[Locked] AS [Locked]
FROM [dbo].[NativeAnalyses] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[OwnerID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[FolderID] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1
```

And SignedNativeAnalysis just inherits NativeAnalysis with one extra property.

```
internal class SignedNativeAnalysis : NativeAnalysis
{
   public bool IsSigned { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
As per suggested I tried to use an expression to achieve the result I wanted but I got an exception instead:

```
Expression<Func<NativeAnalysis, SignedNativeAnalysis>> signed = p => Select(p);
myTable.Where(p => p.OwnerID.Equals(owner) && p.FolderID == folderId)
       .Select(signed)
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'SignedNativeAnalysis
>   Select(OverseerUI.EntityFramework.NativeAnalysis)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick. Entity Framework Select doesn't take a Func<T, U>. It takes an Expression<Func<T, U>>.

So when you pass the lambda, the compiler converts your lambda into an Expression, pass it to EF, which converts the expression into SQL code.

When you pass a Func<T, U> there's no way to convert it to an Expression. The Enumerable.Select extension method -- which takes a plain Func, not an Expression -- kicks in instead. So EF execute the first part, up to the Where, in SQL. Then the results are passed to Linq to Object that executes the projection in memory.

You can still do dynamic stuff, but you have to create an instance of Expression, not a delegate.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to use an expression however this does not work as I get the "this method cannot be translated to an expression" error?

Comment: I've seen your edited question. What you've done is just creating the "Call Select(p) method" expression. But EF doesn't know how to convert "Call Select(p)" into SQL code. This is not what you want. What you want is the "p => new SignedNativeAnalysis { ID = p.ID, ... }" expression.

Comment: Yes, that's great.  but that's essentially my first option wrapped in an expression.  I want the second option (using a function) so I could use the selecting in multiple places and not have to duplicate it...?

Comment: You cannot use a compiled function. But you can still store the expression in a field/variable/static and share it around your code. Like: _Expression<Func<NativeAnalysis, SignedNativeAnalysis>> projection = p => new ...;_ and then use it _myTable.Where(...).Select(projection);_

Comment: This link may help by providing more details about Expressions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bashmohandes/archive/2006/06/12/c-3-0-lambda-expressions-and-expression-trees.aspx